# PHP CURL saves cookie into cookiejar but doesn't use it

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a PHP script which uses CURL to log into a site with a simple login page. It sends an initial request to the site and sees if it's already logged in (due to cookies) or if the login page comes up - and if it does, logs in.

However, recently I noticed that every time the script runs it is never logged in. Deep diving into the headers using VERBOSE shows that the cookie in the COOKIEFILE/COOKIEJAR is never used, only the cookies that are received by the site for that particular session. If I manually add cookies to the cookiejar in the middle of the run (something that used to work) - it doesn't work anymore as the cookies in the COOKIEFILE aren't actually used.

This happens both locally and on the production server, meaning it doesn't seem to be a system issue. I created test versions for other login pages with the same results. 
I use a fullpath to the cookie file (which is updated with cookies, just not used) and use curl_close().

Following is the CURL function:

```
private function curlPage($url, $postParameters) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParameters);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
    if ($this->verbose == 1) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->defaultTimeout); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    $pageResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $pageResponse;
}
```

Following is the verbose response of the CURL request to the main page, where it is supposed to check whether or not it is logged in. As the site is of a client, I redacted it.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: *********
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying : *********...
* Connected to : ********* (*********) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.6 Safari/600.6.3
Host: *********
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2016 20:42:22 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
* Server ********* is not blacklisted
< Server: *********
<
```

As can be seen - no cookie in sight, despite having a COOKIEFILE available.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first you must make sure `__DIR__` have write permission.

The second when you run code. You can check `cookie.txt` file had been create or not.

The third you must use ONE cookie for all session. So the victim know you logged in.

And try my source

```
$cookies = tempnam('/tmp','cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
```

Comment: Deleting cookie files and running the script again resulted in cookie files being generated.

Comment: Interestingly, it does seem to be a permissions issue. Saving to a different directory seems to do the trick. Thanks for the tip! Do you know what chmod should the cookie directory have? Thanks!

Comment: Already did, I just don't have enough reputation for the upvote to be publicly displayed.

Comment: The chmod didn't seem to do the trick. For some reason the behavior is still problematic. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @Idan You can try with 644 first. If your source not working let use 755.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/126073/chmod-to-allow-read-and-write-permissions-for-directory

Comment: Thanks again. still not sure what's causing this, but I just created a subdirectory within the directory and it works. Weird, but at least now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same issue (running as root, so permissions were not the issue). The CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE fixed it for me.  
It is weird tho... On other scripts it is working just fine with just the COOKIEJAR.