# php emulate going to a webpage that constantly changes cookie

Tags: php, cookies, file-get-contents, request-headers

I have a webpage that I'd like to go to programmatically with PHP.  I can go to that webpage "by hand" with chrome, right-click "inspect element" and find the cookie that is getting used when I visit the page.

I then created a context with PHP like:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie:bla bla bla\r\n".
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
  )
);


$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

and this will work for a few times.... but very quickly it stops working.  When I go to the web page again by hand I find that the cookie has changed.

So how can I emulate this changing cookie with php?  I know that when I use the browser by hand, somehow it updates my cookie automatically and I don't ever have to worry about it.  Can I fetch this information somehow?  I've read about get_headers() and getallheaders(), but they both seem to be giving me response headers.  It's the request headers that are changing.

So... I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL and let it keep cookies between requests.  Here's an SO question talking about it that you can pull an example from.

[PHP CURL saves cookie into cookiejar but doesn't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490527/php-curl-saves-cookie-into-cookiejar-but-doesnt-use-it)

Comment: yeah... but how do I get the new cookies that seem to be automagically generated when I visit the website by hand?

Comment: The cookiejar continues to update as you visit different pages.  It's basically emulating a real browser if you set a user agent.