# Curl Login + login page

Tags: php, curl

Id got this code, It all works, the cookie is added to the txt file, the login happens, It displays the login page all fine once logged in.

My issue is loading the next page. So I'm logged in, cookie is made, I now need to load the next page which is normally hidden without being logged in.

I don't know how :( Here is my code:

```
// options
$EMAIL            = '####################';
$PASSWORD         = '####################';
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";
$LOGINURL         = "####################"; 
$agent            = "Nokia-Communicator-WWW-Browser/2.0 (Geos 3.0 Nokia-9000i)";


// begin script
$ch = curl_init(); 

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($content);
$fields['loginid'] = $EMAIL;
$fields['passwd'] = $PASSWORD;

// get x value that is used in the login url
$x = '';
if (preg_match('/myauthenticate\.jsp\?x=(\d+)/i', $content, $match)) {
    $x = $match[1];
}

$LOGINURL   = "####################/myauthenticate.jsp?x=$x";

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 

// change URL to login URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

// perform login
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

function getFormFields($data)
{
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);
        return $inputs;
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $inputs;
}
```

So this all works, but now I need to close that script, and start the next page load reading the cookie file to see the data of a logged in page.

Could someone please help :(

Comment: Hey. You should share the real website and test credentials to check this out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL saves cookie into cookiejar but doesn't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490527/php-curl-saves-cookie-into-cookiejar-but-doesnt-use-it)

Comment: @rinsadahmed no can do, it's live data. The cookie is created and the script works, that's not an issue. it's nothing wrong with the script above, the question is how to use the cookie that is created to load the next page.

Comment: @martinzeitler this is different, my script works, there is nothing wrong with my script. My issue is addition to. I'm not sure how to use the cookie created and session started to load the next page whilst remaining signed in.

Comment: Well, parsing secure sites are complicated. Cookies are not the only thing to consider. Without the login detail it is hard to say what you are really missing on the 2nd call

Comment: Okay thanks @martinZeitler, real useful. If you looked at my code though, If you look at the link you provided me. They use them both as well. Pretty much like every other resource i've managed to find.

Comment: @rinsadAhmed thanks, yes I agree, but I do get a successful login, and cookie is added to the cookie.txt file showing it added fine, and I am logged in, the return is my logged in page. So it logs in fine. I am also 100% they only use cookie to hold session.

Answer (score 0):

the one `_JAR` option is used to store cookies when receiving them, the other `_FILE` option is used to read cookies, in order to post them back. make sure the `apache` user has read/write access on that file, eg. as the owner of it (which appears most likely to be the culprit here).

therefore I'd say: `touch cookie.txt` and `chown apache:apache ./cookie.txt` ...while during test, you can do a `cat ./cookie.txt` to verifiy after the inital request, if something has changed.